# simplification of conjunction of inequalities in z3

Tags: z3

It is easy to see, that conjunction of two following inequalities could be simplified to one equality.

```
(declare-const x  Int)
(declare-const y  Int)
(assert ( and ( <= ( + (* -1 x) y ) -1 ) ( <=( + (* -1 y) x ) 1 )))
(apply (and-then simplify propagate-ineqs))
```

I try different tactics, but wanted result was not obtained. Could you, please, specify tactic for this case?